# Parsing regular expressions coming out of GetSchema's Common Schema Collection

Tags: c#, .net, sql, regex, schema

I have an unknown connection being passed in, through the base `DbConnection`, it could be MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, SQL Server, Access, I don't know.

I need to pull the quoted identifiers out of the schema information, I've figured out how to get the quoted identifiers, but it comes back in a RegEx, and I'm not familiar enough with RegEx to be able to parse these dynamically.

Given the C# code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper
{
    internal char LeftIdentifier { get; private set; }

    internal char RightIdentifier { get; private set; }

    private void SetQuotedIdentifiers(DbConnection connection)
    {
        string quotedIdentifier = connection.GetSchema("DataSourceInformation").Rows[0]["QuotedIdentifierPattern"].ToString();
        LeftIdentifier = null; // some code I have to figure out
        RightIdentifier = null; // some code I have to figure out
    }
}
```

I need help setting the values of `LeftIdentifier`, and `RightIdentifier`.

If I run that code, with an Oracle connection, `quotedIdentifier` comes back with the following result:

```
(([^\"]\"\")*)
```

I want to set `LeftIdentifier` in this case equal to **"** and `RightIdentifier` also to **"**

If I run that code, with a SQL Server connection, `quotedIdentifier` comes back with the following result:

```
(([^\\[]|\\]\\])*)
```

In this case, I want to set `LeftIdentifier` to **[** and RightIdentifier equal to **]**

Can anyone help with the code needed for this? I'm hitting a stumbling block with everything I'm trying.

*Note: I got the information for the function from this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254501.aspx).*

Comment: Both these regexes match empty strings... Can identifiers actually be empty??

Comment: it should be matching empty strings, I'm looking for the stuff that goes around the empty string, for instance the "" or the [], or ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on Ignore Pattern whitespace for this pattern. Here I have escaped the identifiers as the hex values.

```
string pattern = #"
# \x28 (
# \x29 )
# \x22 "
# \x5B [
# \x5D ]

(?:[\x28\x29\x22\x5B\x5D])        # match but don't caputure the set above
(?<Text>[^\x28\x29\x22\x5B\x5D]+) # Get the inbetween text into Text capture group
(?:[\x28\x29\x22\x5B\x5D])        # match but don't caputure the set above    
";
```

or as a single line without the ignore

```
string pattern = @"(?:[\x28\x29\x22\x5B\x5D])(?<Text>[^\x28\x29\x22\x5B\x5D]+)(?:[\x28\x29\x22\x5B\x5D])";
```

Will match

"abc"
[abc]
(ab)

and returns the text abc in the named capture group named Text.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not trying to parse it for text, I'm trying to parse the actual regular expression's for the [ and ] or the " and "

Comment: Regardless, relooking at it, I actually figured out what I needed to do from your answer! :)

Comment: @BrianDeragon Looking at other's patterns adds new things to one's own patterns. Glad to be of help regardless. :-)