# Extract database provider's delimiters from a regular expression

Tags: c#, sql, regex, oracle, ado.net

I have an opened connection with ADO.Net and I'am retrieving the datasource Information. The connection can be SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, ODBC...

When I execute the following code :

`DataTable collection = connection.GetSchema("DataSourceInformation");`

it returns a lot of information including the **QuotedIdentifierPattern**. This one is returned as an ReGex :

For SQL it returns : `(([^\[]|\]\])*)`

And For Oracle it returns : `"^(([^"]|"")*)$"`

I'm wondering if there's a way to reverse engineer the ReGex to retrieve the delimiters (left and right) for the providers ?
The result should be :

For SQL : **[** for the left delimiter and **]** for the right delimiter

For Oracle : **"** for the left delimiter and **"** for the right delimiter

> A similar question was asked but there's no concluent answer :
>   [Parsing regular expressions coming out of GetSchema's Common Schema Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749959/parsing-regular-expressions-coming-out-of-getschemas-common-schema-collection)

**Edit**

When I use `DbCommandBuilder.QuotePrefix` it works for most of the providers except OLE DB and ODBC. Here is an exemple of what the DbCommandBuilder returns.
[image: Connections to test]

I called `DbCommandBuilder.QuotePrefix` and `DbCommandBuilder.QuoteSuffix`by using a SQL Server provider, an OLE DB and an ODBC providers and the result is the following:

[image: Result of QuotePrefix and QuoteSuffix]

So now my main concern is to make is work with OLE DB and ODBC.

Comment: It is not quite clear: if the regex patterns are fixed, why not check them with mere string check method? I.e. something like `if (regex == @"(([^\[]|\]\])*)") QuotedIdentifierPattern = "[";`

Comment: they are not fixed, this is just an exemple for SQL Server provider with a specific driver. but when i use an odbc provider to connect to an SQL server database it can return me another regex. (because for SQL Server we can have **[** and also **"** as delimiter). In another hand, we are using a lot of provider and we dont know in advance the  result of the function for all the provider we may use

Comment: The OP wants a solution that works whatever the provider that it's used. Sometimes you can use oledb  or odbc and you really don't know the identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reverse-engineering these from the `QuotedIdentifierPattern`, use [`DbCommandBuilder.QuotePrefix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.quoteprefix) and [`QuoteSuffix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.quotesuffix).

```
var builder = SqlClientFactory.Instance.CreateCommandBuilder();
var prefix = builder.QuotePrefix; // [
var suffix = builder.QuoteSuffix; // ]

var builder = OracleClientFactory.Instance.CreateCommandBuilder();
var prefix = builder.QuotePrefix; // "
var suffix = builder.QuoteSuffix; // "

var builder = MySqlClientFactory.Instance.CreateCommandBuilder();
var prefix = builder.QuotePrefix; // `
var suffix = builder.QuoteSuffix; // `
```

Comment: This solution does not work with oleDb and odbc connection. Returns always blank prefix and suffix.

Comment: This solution works for most of the providers except OLEDB and ODBC, i edited the question by the way. thx